# Reaching a middle ground between search() and findall() in regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

A personal project requiring me to create regular expressions for IP addresses led me to the following standoff.

```
pattern = r'123\.145\.167\.[0-9]{1,2}'
source = "123.145.167.0, 123.145.167.99, 123.145.167.100"
n = re.search(pattern, source)
print n.group()


pattern = r'123\.145\.167\.[0-9]{1,2}'
source = "123.145.167.0, 123.145.167.99, 123.145.167.100"
n = re.compile(pattern)
print n.findall(source)
```

While using search matches only the first element in the source string, findall creates a problem by giving an output such as this

```
['123.145.167.0', '123.145.167.99', '123.145.167.10']
```

Is it possible that I can obtain the matches for both 123.145.167.0 and 123.145.167.99 and not the 123.145.167.100 ?

I have already gone thorough [python - regex search and findall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110059/python-regex-search-and-findall) and yet not able to understand how I can solve my problem.

Comment: You may want to understand what word boundaries are.  Moreover, there is a basic difference between `re.search()` and `re.findall()`.

Answer (score 1):

Throw a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) on the end: `\b`.

```
pattern = r'123\.145\.167\.[0-9]{1,2}\b'
source = "123.145.167.0, 123.145.167.99, 123.145.167.100"
n = re.compile(pattern)
print n.findall(source)
```

[Gives:](http://codepad.org/jUOeMM8x)

```
['123.145.167.0', '123.145.167.99']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *lookahead assertion*:

```
pattern = r'123\.145\.167\.[0-9]{1,2}(?=[^0-9]|$)'
```

the part

```
(?=[^0-9]|$)
```

means that you just want to **check** if following there is either a non-numeric character or the string ends. This check will not "use" any char and will only influence if the expression matches or not. With this approach `findall` will provide the result you're looking for.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> (?=...) Matches if ... matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the
>   string. This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, Isaac
>   (?=Asimov) will match 'Isaac ' only if it’s followed by 'Asimov'.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define a boundry for your match. `123.145.167.10` is within `123.145.167.100`. You can use the `\b` tag to define a boundry.

```
r"\b123\.145\.167\.[0-9]{1,2}\b"
```