# Regex backreference findall not working

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, findall, backreference

I have recently been using regexes in a program. In this program I used them to find words in a list of words that matched a certain RE. However, when i tried backreferencing with this program, I got an interesting result.

Here is the code:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"[abcgr]([a-z])\1[ldc]")
string = "reel reed have that with this they"
print(re.findall(pattern, string))
```

What I expected was the result `["reel","reed"]` (the regex matched these when I used it with [Pythex](http://pythex.org/))

However, when I ran the code using python (I use 3.5.1) I got the following result:

`['e','e']`

Please can someone with more experience with REs explain why I am getting this problem and what I can do to resolve it.

Thank you.

Comment: pythex gave same result... `e` and `e`....

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Sorry, I meant when I tried simply matching the regex with "reel" and "reed", I didn't try to use findall in Pythex.

Comment: a possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110059/python-regex-search-and-findall

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) only returns captured values captured with *capturing groups* inside the regex pattern.

Use [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) that will keep the zeroth group (the whole match):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'[abcgr]([a-z])\1[ldc]')
s = "reel reed have that with this they"
print([x.group(0) for x  in p.finditer(s)])
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/pTZDxg)