# Trying to understand re.search() vs re.findall()

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to understand a seemingly easy case while learning regular expressions.

Suppose I have a code like this:

```
import re

a = "Eventin queue contains 5 elements, first element is 20 minutes old"
b = re.search(r"Eventin queue contains \d+ elements, first element is \d+ minutes old", a)
print(b)
```

For some reason, `b`only returns this result: `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 66), match='Eventin queue contains 5 elements, first element >`

As you can see, it's not a full result that I was expecting. However, if I use `re.findall()` I get `['Eventin queue contains 5 elements, first element is 20 minutes old']`

Am I misunderstanding something here? Shouldn't `re.search()` return the full match as well?

Comment: Did you take a look at docs?

Comment: `re.search` returns *a match object* or `None`. This is clearly documented. `re.findall` returns a *list of `str` objets*. Again, this is clearly documented.

Comment: The representation (i.e. printing) of the match object doesn't show you everything that matched, you need to query it.

Comment: Did you search SO before asking the question? [what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match/180993) or [python-regex-search-and-findall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110059/python-regex-search-and-findall)? **Research first**, then ask.Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read it. Both explain various `re`gex methods in detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `re.findall` returns a list of matched substrings, but the method `re.search` returns a `match` object, you can recover the full matched substring like this.

```
b.group() # 'Eventin queue contains 5 elements, first element is 20 minutes old'
```

What you were seeing, `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 66), match='Eventin queue contains 5 elements, first element >`, is only a representation of the object.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. Thank you.

Comment: Happens to us all, but the re module is very well documented, I encourage you to read the doc for further questions: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html